# Delphi Seattle remembers past directories in the dcc command line

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Delphi (XE8, Seattle and Berlin) seems to remember the invalid paths. As shown in the third picture, these paths are only valid on my old laptop, but when I copied the project to my current desktop, it shouldn't remember these, and I can't find anywhere else that stores these paths.

The dcc32 and dcc64 both save these invalid paths in the command line.

How can I delete these invalid paths?

[image: Project Directory]

[image: Paths Configuration]

[image: Invalid Paths]

Comment: How about pressing the <delete-invalid-paths> button?

Comment: The invalid paths boxed in red don't appear on the list where that button would apply, @Johan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a **grep -r -e**  command and finally find out where these invalid paths are.

They are in the  *.dproj files so I just removed them in the text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Those bad paths are probably in one of the base configurations. Try selecting one of the ancestor configurations. Paths are "merged" into descendant configurations from the ancestor which is why they don't show up in the dialog.